# 403 error in Laravel storage directory only

Tags: laravel, file-permissions, plesk

I'm currently getting a 403 error on the storage directory.
I have tried the correct file path for both a php artisan link and the regular symlink from command line
The specific path is this one:

```
http://example.com/storage/app/public/category/zASySdXhEtXBaeWoz4KLJoIVLVxm3W6jRr6gHQhN.jpg
```

This is linked to the storage directory:
to here: `example.com/public/storage/*`

I created the symlink like so:

```
ln -s /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/storage /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/public
```

The above directory is for the symlink one but for php artisan link the url is slightly different.

the permissions set for storage before were executed running:

```
chmod -R 775 storage/
```

checking permissions I get this:

```
ls -la ./httpdocs
```

```
drwxr--r--   5 pacer psacln          46 Apr  8  2021 storage
```

Everything else works except the storage directory.  I've seen the other questions regarding 403 and have attempted those fixes but nothing is working.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: (pacer psacln psaserv) which has ownership of the directory ?
you can use chown to change permissions and make them sync first then try it again

Comment: I could be wrong but im not sure if your suppose to create a symlink to the entire storage folder vs a directory within the folder. For example in the past with laravel i have use the following command. "php artisan storage:link" Will create a link in public folder that is a symbolik link to the storage/app/public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while spent on this the error was caused because I ran the php artisan storage:link and ln -s link with root.  Therefore the link was unaccessible by my server for public consumption.

My solution was to switch to user:

```
su myUser
```

Then run the php artisan storage:link

Answer (score 1):

The storage link points directly to the "app/public" folder.
So the link address will look like this :

```
http://example.com/storage/category/zASySdXhEtXBaeWoz4KLJoIVLVxm3W6jRr6gHQhN.jpg
```

Comment: How are you arriving at this conclusion? The storage link doesn't have storage/category... it's /storage/app/public/category/ that's the directory with in the storage directory.

Comment: This is documented here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#the-public-disk The symlink actually allows you to access the `storage` via the `public` folder which is the root for your app when being accessed via your domain.

Comment: @Johannes but the symlink was created via ssh like so: ln -s /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/storage /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/public this was explained in the question

Comment: @FabricioG Your files are in the "/storage/app/public/category/" path, but symlink is linked to the "app/public" path, so it does not have the "app/public" link address.

Comment: @Mohammad my bro the symlink is pointing to public so I'm using the full path.... if the link was broke then it would give a 404 NOT a 403 this produces a 403: storage/app/public/attribute_item/6XUd80jcd2A8lQl0xrlOAH4182nyJjJLi18CncDU.svg.

Comment: @Mohammad and also your suggestion does not work.  I tried it.

Comment: @FabricioG your destination is wong. Try to change `ln -s /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/storage/app/public /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/public/storage` or `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: @WahyuKristianto both attempted 403 persists...

Comment: Are there any routes defined in the route middleware that enforce authentication for this route? You can also install [Laravel Telescope](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/telescope) and check the logs there

Answer (score 0):

first : run commint

```
php artisan storage:link



http://example.com/storage/category/zASySdXhEtXBaeWoz4KLJoIVLVxm3W6jRr6gHQhN.jpg
```